# Q:how to use a specific element to locate anothor equative element by protractor?

Tags: protractor

im a new bee of protractor .
 here is the code:

```
    // fist line
<table class="table">
<tbody class="table-body">
    <tr class="table-tree" ng-repeat="items in page">
         <td class="checkbox" >
              <input type="checkbox">
         <td class="node-name">
              <span class="node-icon" title="tree">

// second line
    <tr class="table-tree" ng-repeat="items in page">
         <td class="checkbox" >
              <input type="checkbox">
         <td class="node-name">
              <span class="node-icon" title="flower">

// third line
    <tr class="table-tree" ng-repeat="items in page">
         <td class="checkbox" >
              <input type="checkbox">
         <td class="node-name">
              <span class="node-icon" title="flower">
</tbody>
</table>
```

Im want to click the sencond checkbox , and the first line is not always present, so i cant use $$('.checkbox').get(1) to get it, so I trying to locate the first checkbox where has [title = "flower"], then I write this:

```
var a = $$('[title="flower"]').get(0).getWebElement();
var b = a.getDriver().findElement(by.css('.checkbox'));
b.click();
```

but when the process finish , the first line checkbox was be click,
whats the wrong? and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

try `$$('[title="flower"]').get(0).$('.checkbox').click()`

Answer (score 0):

First of all: why do you use `.getWebElement()` and `.getDriver()`?

What is you error message?

@Vlad's solution would be ok, but `checkbox` is not an ancestor of `flower`.

You need to get `tr`, check whether it contains `title="flower"` and if so, click `checkbox` of `tr`.

I won't write code for you, but you can check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48020146/6331748 and adjust code for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1)** Use XPath

```
element(by.xpath('//tr[td/span[@title="flower"]]/td[1]/input')).click();
```

**Option 2)** Use element() chain

```
// find the `SPAN` which title is flowser <br>
element(by.css('span[title="flower"]')) <br>
// find parent of `SPAN` until `TR` <br>
.element(by.xpath('./../..')) <br>
// find the `input` inside the first `TD` of above `TR` <br>
.element(by.xpath('./td[1]/input'))
```