# ElementFinder.filter function not returning a value when boolean result is true

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor, cucumber

I'm trying to run a test using protractor to count the number of rows in a table. The page I'm testing has 5 tables which are loaded, these tables don't have Id parameters but they do have distinct names in their respective table header rows. I'm therefore extracting all table elements and then filtering using a function which checks the text inside the first th tagged row.

To extract the number of rows I'm using code similar to this:

```
// Step definition - used in cucumber.
Given(/^the (\w+) table should have (\d+) rows$/, 
      async (tableName, expectedRowCount) => {

    const parsedRowCount = Number.parseInt(expectedRowCount);

    const actualRowCount =
        await element
            .$$('table')
            .filter(async (elem, _) => {
                const textValue = await elem.$$('th').first().getText();
                console.log(`${textValue} = ${tableName} => ${textValue === tableName}`)
                return textValue === tableName;
            })
            .first()
            .$$('tr')
            .count();

    assert.strictEqual(actualRowCount, parsedRowCount);    
});
```

When this runs the console.log prints "Account = Account => true" for the table I want to print, and a false statement for everything else.

If I try to debug and find out how many elements are passing through the filter function:

```
// Step definition - used in cucumber.
Given(/^the (\w+) table should have (\d+) rows$/, 
      async (tableName, expectedRowCount) => {

    const parsedRowCount = Number.parseInt(expectedRowCount);

    const actualRowCount =
        await element
            .$$("table"))
            .filter(async (elem, _) => {
                const textValue = await elem.$$('th').first().getText();
                console.log(`${textValue} = ${tableName} => ${textValue === tableName}`)
                return textValue === tableName;
            })            
            .count();

    assert.strictEqual(actualRowCount, parsedRowCount);    
});
```

I find that there are actually no elements passing through the filter function. I don't understand why there are no elements being passed on, when the console.log clearly shows that the return value from the table I'm interested in will return true. If instead of passing in an element argument and pass in an index argument (the second argument for the filter function) with some condition such as `index === 1` then the right table gets passed through and the answer comes out right.

Can someone explain why my filter function doesn't work?

Comment: Please confirm all `table` on that page has at least one `th`, otherwise `elem.$$('th').first()` should throw exception

Comment: My first question on stackoverflow was very similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48016927/protractor-script-doesnt-work-properly Since then I realized that the whole approach was wrong, even though I was able to solve it, because it may go wrong in so many places. If you attach your html doc and ping me in comment I'll show you a bunch of better approaches to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Add some code to check there is `th` in table or not.

```
.filter(async (elem, _) => {
    const thCount = await elem.$$('th').count();

    if(thCount > 0) {
      console.log(`there are ${thCount} ths`);

      const textValue = await elem.$$('th').first().getText();
      console.log(`${textValue} = ${tableName} => ${textValue === tableName}`)
      return textValue === tableName;   
    }
    else {
        console.log("there are 0 ths");
        return false;
    }
})
```

Or you can add `catch()` to see any failure occur in `filter()`

```
.filter(async (elem, _) => {
    const textValue = await elem.$$('th').first().getText();
    console.log(`${textValue} = ${tableName} => ${textValue === tableName}`)
    return textValue === tableName;
})            
.count()
.catch(function(err){
    console.log('error: ' + err)
})
```